# Adding a field to all documents MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

So I want to add a field called `MiddleName` to all documents in my collection

```
db.users.updateMany({}, {$set: {MiddleName: ""}});
```

but for some reason the code above doesn't do anything to my documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the multi:true flag. It will update the existing documents in that collection.

```
db.users.update({}, {$set : {"MiddleName": ""}}, {multi:true});
```

Comment: Can you mention the response you are getting? Or, any error?

Comment: I was being stupid, I just needed to actually add "MiddleName" to the schema document